# Python: How to get the id field inside of dictionary that's inside of a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to get the ID of dict which satisfies the condition (if current day is on any schedule)

```
arr = [
  {
    "schedule": "Mon - Wed - Fri",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "schedule": "Mon - Tue - Wed - Thu - Fri",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "schedule": "Fri - Sat - Sun",
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "schedule": "Mon - Wed - Fri - Sat",
    "id": 4
  },
  {
    "schedule": "Sat - Sun - Mon - Tue",
    "id": 5
  }
]
```

Ive tried:

```
day = "Wed"

for listArr in arr:
    array = listArr.values()
    str1 = " - ".join(array)
    strArr = str1.split(" - ")

    if any(day in i for i in strArr):
        print(strArr)
```

Im getting:

```
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, int found
```

What i want:

```
[1, 2, 4]
```

I tried to convert int into str but it returns null or blank.. any help?

Answer (score 1):

```
day = "Wed"
print([l['id'] for l in arr if day in l['schedule']])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making this much harder than it needs to be. You just need to get the `id` value of each item within the list.

So:

```
for item in arr:
    if day in item['schedule']
        print(item['id'])
```

Although if you need to collect the IDs rather than just printing them, a list comprehension would be better:

```
result = [item['id'] for item in arr if day in item['schedule']]
```